# Return to default OnClickListener Navigation Drawer Icon

Tags: android, onclick, navigation-drawer, onclicklistener, android-toolbar

I want to change the OnClickListener of my navigation drawer icon on the toolbar. After do that, I want return to the default behavior and OnClickListener of Navigation Drawer icon.

Here my code:

```
private void changeToolbarSelection(){
    String title;
    if(inSelectionMode()) {
        title = mContext.getString(R.string.selected, selectedPos.size());
        mActivity.getToolbar().setNavigationIcon(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.back_arrow));
        mActivity.getToolbar().setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clearSelections();
                LOG.info(TAG, "Back arrow pressed in Selection mode");
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        title = mContext.getString(R.string.list_tab_title);
        mActivity.getmDrawerToggle().syncState();
        mActivity.getToolbar().setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Here I need to return on default OnClickListener
            }
        });
    }
    mActivity.getToolbar().setTitle(title);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, don't set the navigation icon and `OnClickListener` on the `Toolbar` directly. Set them through the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, with the `setHomeAsUpIndicator()` and `setToolbarNavigationClickListener()` methods, and use `setDrawerIndicatorEnabled()` method to switch between the toggle and regular navigation.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this:

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Toolabr: on Click menu option selected");

            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(YourActivity.this);

        }
    });
```